# JDBI - What's the difference between @define and @bind in JDBI?

Tags: java, sql, jdbi

Are both functions sanitized / safe against SQL injection? For example, consider the following:

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO <tableName> (<columns>) VALUES (<values>)")
    public abstract void addRowToDataset(@Define("tableName") String tableName, @Define("columns") String columns, @BindIn("values") Collection<Object> values);
```

My current understanding is that `@define` literally inserts the string as is into the query, but `@bind` does sanitization. So if we control the `columns` and tableName `parameters` and only the `values` parameter is user input, then we should be fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I came across the same question and found the answer surprisingly difficult to find. A colleague tells me it was sort of just common knowledge a programming-generation ago, so maybe its documentation was forgotten as software evolved.

In fact, Oracle's [Binding and Defining](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm) at first seems promising, but is completely misleading, as its "Defining" refers to setting up references to retrieve results, which is not at all what it means in JDBI.

Here is what they actually mean, if my colleague is correct:

- `@Define` is for constants, and interpolates the format `<field>`.
- `@Bind` is for variables, and interpolates the format `:field` (a "named parameter"). You are correct: a side-effect of binding is that sanitization occurs.
- `@BindIn` is for lists, and interpolates the format `(element IN (<field>))`. The elements are also sanitized.

My mistake was using the `<field>` format for a `@Bind` parameter, which resulted in the interpolation always being an empty string.

Comment: I assumed all the queries in jndi are prepared statements and in which case how does using define cause sql injection if values not sanitized.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the most upvoted answer. I just want to add that, according to my tests and interpretations:

- @Bind is mostly used for places where you query and update/create data. Per example after the `WHERE` and `VALUES(...)`
- @Define is mostly used in other parts of a SQL statement, like in places with conditions or in ORDER BY per example:

```kotlin
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY <orderByWinsOrPlays>") 
fun getPlayerRankings(@Define orderByWinsOrPlays: String)
```

Replacing `<orderByWinsOrPlays>` with `:orderByWinsOrPlays` and replacing `@Define` with `@Bind("orderByWinsOrPlays")` will not work, but it will not throw an error. Testing these 2 options back in forth lead me to this conclusion. And the type parameter annotated with @Define should be a primitive object, preferably, or it won't work. For complex objects, use @BindBean